# Gradle sync issues: ERROR: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am using the android studio 3.4.2 . When creating a new project i am getting the following error, 
"Gradle sync issues: ERROR: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
This is also happening when I'm opening some of my previous projects. I have tried turning off the corporate network and proxy and using my own network connection but the error still persists. anyone who has a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, when you turn off the proxy for the corporate network, the "gradle.properties" file does not clear the proxy network proxy settings. Navigate to the file in android studio and comment out the proxy settings. Hope this helps someone.